# Coefficient of Logistic Regression

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

Fitted a logistic regression to predict if a member would default the loan payment. The coefficient for 'loan_amnt' is positive as shown below:
[image]

As it is positive, **an increase in loan_amnt would mean that odds/probability of 'defaulting' also increases.**

But, the average defaults based on quartile of loan_amnt indicates that **average number of defaulters decrease with increasing loan_amnt.**

[image: figure-2]

columns(quartile, no of members, no of defaulters, average). Here the members is classified as Defaulter or Non-Defaulter.

How can they different ?

Comment: Are you controlling for other variables in your regression model?

Comment: what is 'controlling a variable' ? i am new to statistics and machine learning. I have included some of the variables, but not all, while fitting the model.

Comment: Put another way, is that the full output of your regression model?  I believe I know what your problem is, and I'm guessing that your regression model includes more variables than just loan_amnt.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is NOT the full output of the regression model. The model is fitted with other variables along with loan_amt.

Comment: have added the full coefficient list in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Confounding variables!

I don't have the time to sketch out a longer answer, but the basic idea is that you have confounding variables.

Just to make up an illustrative example - Imagine that having a higher loan amount (all else being equal) increases your default rate, and that being very wealthy (all else being equal) decreases your default rate dramatically.

The regression model tells you that, "on its own" (in a rough sense), a higher loan amount increases the default rate.  That's how you get your first result

However, those who have a higher loan amount might also tend to be richer.  Each of your quantiles might be so much richer than the last, that the effect of being richer (driving down default rate) offsets the effect of having higher loan amounts.  Something like this could explain your second result.

Comment: Got a negative coefficient and a negative intercept when I fitted a model just on the loan_amnt. Does this support your answer ? Could you point out some resources on fitting regression model. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is consistent with my answer, yes.  Not sure of a good introductory resource, but looking for tutorials on the basics of linear regression would be a place to start

Comment: The model fitted on just loan_amnt had a **negative** coefficient for the variable, whereas the model with more parameters had a **positive** coefficient for loan_amnt. How can this flip ?

Comment: The regression gives you the impact of loan_amnt "assuming all other variables in this model are held constant".  So when you include all the other factors, the intuition is that the model is able to hold them constant and give you the impact of just loan_amnt.  But if you don't include other variables, then it has no way of knowing that a confounding variable might exist

Comment: thanks !!! now things started getting clearer. Will read about them

Answer (score 2):

Thought experiment.  Suppose you take five identical copies of one person, and lend each of them 10, 100, 1000, 10000, and 100000 dollars.  Which copy would be more likely to default?

Now suppose you go to a bank and find (different) people that were loaned 10, 100, 1000, 10000, and 100000 dollars, who would be more likely to default?

In the first case, the more you loan to the person, the more likely they are to default.  Since you have 5 copies of the same person, their means to repay the loan are fixed, so the more you loan, the more stress it puts on their fixed finances to repay.  This is what your regression coefficient is capturing.  It is the rate of change of (the log odds of) default as the load amount is varied **as all other measurements are held equal**..

In the second case, the people you find that the bank has loaned more to will have better financial means than those receiving small loans.  This makes them more able to weather financial stresses, and less likely to attempt to spend out of their means.  This is what your summary table is capturing.

Comment: seems like you too have given the same explanation, but I can only accept one answer, my apologize.